# Check properties of object is null

Tags: c#, .net

I have `List` of Albums objects (photo albums for example). I check properties of the object is null.

Just example:

```
if (albums.Last() != null 
      && albums.Last().Photos != null 
      && albums.Last().Photos.Description != null) { //action }
```

Can I do this check shorter in code?

Comment: Wait next c# release. Nowadays you cannot

Comment: C# is language not a Magic

Comment: You can use combination of expressions and Reflection - here is my complete code for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429112/how-can-i-manage-the-onslaught-of-null-checks/20434899#20434899

Comment: What about `try { //action } catch (NullReferenceException){}`? I guess its not good practice to ignore exceptions?

Comment: @derape: you centainly don't want the overhead of exception handling for something simple like this.

Comment: Why don't create a Method to handle this in the object itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

BTW:

1. use vars instead of calling a function all the time(`Last()`).
2. use `LastOrDefault()` and prevent crashes.

   ```
   var lastAlbum = albums.LastOrDefault();
   if(lastAlbum != null && lastAlbum.Photos != null && lastAlbum.Photos.Description != null){//action}
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Just wrap it in a function:

```
public static bool IsInitialized(a Album) {
    return a != null &&
        a.Photos != null &&
        a.Photos.Description != null;
}
```

Then your calling code becomes:

```
var album = albums.LastOrDefault();

if (Album.IsInitialized(album)) {
    // its fine
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an Extension Method -

```
public static class ListExtension {
     public static bool IsLastPhotoNotNull(this List<Album> albums){
          var album = albums.LastOrDefault();
          return album != null && album.Photos != null && album.Photos.Description != null;
     }
}
```

Then call it with the list

```
List<Album> albums;

if(!albums.IsLastPhotoNotNull()){
    //...do other actions
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shorter, no. But more efficient, yes.

You are calling the `Last()` method multiple times. That could harm performance if there are for example database actions involved in that call.

Pull the method outside the `if`:

```
var last = albums.Last();
if (last != null 
  && last.Photos != null 
  && last.Photos.Description != null)
{ //action }
```