# How to check null collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the algorithm that select a data from collection of `reportData`

```
private IDictionary<Guid, JobStatistic> GetAgentsStatistics(IList<Guid> agentIds)
{
     var agentReportItems = from data in reportData
                            from agentId in data.AgentIds
                            where agentIds.Contains(agentId)
                            group data by agentId;
 ...
}
```

But what if agentIds is an empty collection? How to check this situation?

Answer (score 2):

```
 var agentReportItems = from data in reportData
                        from agentId in data.AgentIds
                        where agentIds != null && agentIds.Contains(agentId)
                        group data by agentId;
```

Just check if it's null, and if it's not, then use it as you already did.

Comment: What if it not null, but just has no element?

Comment: @Anatoly What do you want it to do if `agentIds` is empty? `agentIds.Contains(agentId)` will already return `false` if `agentIds` is empty.

Answer (score 2):

The logic you've posted will work for an 'empty collection'

However, assuming you meant null instead of 'empty', this is what an [ArgumentNullException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception(v=vs.110).aspx) would be used for.

[Throwing ArgumentNullException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368742/throwing-argumentnullexception?rq=1)

```
private IDictionary<Guid, JobStatistic> GetAgentsStatistics(IList<Guid> agentIds)
{
    if (agentIds == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("agentIds"); // use nameof(agentIds) instead of "agentIds" if using C# 6 or later

    var agentReportItems = from data in reportData
                           from agentId in data.AgentIds
                           where agentIds.Contains(agentId)
                           group data by agentId;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly check if an enumerable is empty using `.Any()`

```
if (!agentIds.Any()) //It's empty.
{
    throw new ArgumentException("agentIds cannot be empty.");
}
```

Be aware that 'null' does not mean the list is empty. Null would be a complete absence of the list.